# Trying to make a hiscore leaderboard work for my game using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm in over my head right now with PHP and SQL, I'm trying to make a online hi-score leaderboard using an older php example.

Link: https://community.clickteam.com/threads/87185-Online-High-Score-Tutorial

I'm guessing this is way out of date and I attempted to see if I could debug it and check for errors, I did find mysql and try replacing with mysqli but that was a shot in the dark.

Is anyone that can help me make this work.  It's only the php code that is giving me issues, I tried self hosting and using a free host 000webhost as written in the guide.

Unmodified Config.php:

```
<?
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Online Score Script
// Jeff Vance 
// Version 1.4
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// You need to fill in this data from your own mySQL server

// Your host -- for example localhost or mysql.server.com
$mysql_host = "";

// Your user name for mySQL
$mysql_user = "";

// Your password for mySQL
           $mysql_password = "";

// Your database name for mySQL
$mysql_database = "";

// ATTENTION
// This is your secret key - Needs to be the same as the secret key in your game
// You can change this but remember to change it in your game.
// This is used to help secure the score and produce MD5 hashes
           $secret_key = "this is secret";

// Your table name for mySQL
// You can change this is you wish
$tname= 'scores';

// Number of scores to save for each gameid
// Feel free to change this but the example file only lists 10 scores
// You would need to code this
$score_number = '10';

?>
```

Unmodified score_script.php:

```
<?
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Online Score Script
// Jeff Vance 
// Version 1.4
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// WARNING AND READ THIS!
// You don't need to edit this file
// The only file to edit is config.php
// Don't edit this unless you know what your doing :)
// This works out of the box -- your error must be in config.php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Get Configuation file
require("config.php");

// Connect to your server
$db=mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or die (mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die (mysql_error());
    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Check for the existing table if its not found create it
// This is really just here to make the life of new users of the script eaiser
// They won't have to go thru the script and create the table
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(!mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$tname."'")))
{
$query = "CREATE TABLE `$tname` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,`gameid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`playername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`score` int(255) NOT NULL,`scoredate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`md5` varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";

$create_table = mysql_query($query)or die (mysql_error());
// Preload table with 10 scores
$date = date('M d Y');

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Clickteam','100','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Fusion','99','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','is','98','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','awesome','97','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Yves','96','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

           $query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Francois','95','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Jeff','94','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    
$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Simon','93','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Chris','92','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate) values ('1','Nico','91','$date')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());


}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Status Checker
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($_GET["status"])
{
echo "online";
exit;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Run some checks on our gameid 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$gameid_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["gameid"]);
// Check the gameid is numeric
// If its not numberic lets exit
if(!is_numeric($gameid_safe))
{
 exit; 
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Upload new score
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test for the variables submitted by the player
// If they exist upload into the database

if ($_GET["playername"] && $_GET["gameid"] && $_GET["score"])
{

// Strip out | marks submitted in the name or score
$playername_safe = str_replace("|","_",$_GET["playername"]);
$playername_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($playername_safe);
$score_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["score"]);
$date = date('M d Y');
    
// Check the score sent is is numeric
// If the score is not numberic lets exit
if(!is_numeric($score_safe))
{
 exit; 
}

// this secret key needs to be the same as the secret key in your game.
$security_md5= md5($_GET["gameid"].$_GET["playername"].$_GET["score"].$secret_key);

// Check for submitted MD5 different then server generated MD5
if ($security_md5 <>$_GET["code"])
{
// Something is wrong -- MD5 security hash is different
// Could be someone trying to insert bogus score data
exit;
}
// Everything is cool -- Insert the data into the database
$query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate,md5) values ('$gameid_safe','$playername_safe','$score_safe','$date','$security_md5')";
$insert_the_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}
    
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// List high score
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Return a list of high scores with "|" as the delimiter
if ($gameid_safe)
{
$query = "select * from $tname where gameid='$gameid_safe' order by score desc limit 10";
$view_data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($view_data))
    {
    print($row_data["playername"]);
    print "|";
    print ($row_data["score"]);
    print ("|");
    print($row_data["scoredate"]);
    print("|");
    }

// We limit the score database to hold the number defined in the config script
// First check to see how many records we have for this game

$query1 ="select * from $tname where gameid = '$gameid_safe'";
$countresults = mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error());
$countofdeletes = mysql_num_rows($countresults);
if (mysql_num_rows($countresults)>$score_number)
    {
    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM $tname WHERE gameid = '$gameid_safe' ORDER BY score DESC Limit $score_number,$countofdeletes";
    $Get_data = mysql_query($query2)or die (mysql_error());
    while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($Get_data))
    {
    $id_delete = $row_data["id"];
    $query3 = "Delete from $tname where id = $id_delete";
    $Delete_data = mysql_query($query3)or die (mysql_error());
    }
    }
}
    
?>
```

On self hosted system I'm running MariaDB and PHP7.2

This is the output from both:

```
$_GET["code"]) { // Something is wrong -- MD5 security hash is different // Could be someone trying to insert bogus score data exit; } // Everything is cool -- Insert the data into the database $query = "insert into $tname(gameid,playername,score,scoredate,md5) values ('$gameid_safe','$playername_safe','$score_safe','$date','$security_md5')"; $insert_the_data = mysqli_query($query)or die(mysqli_error()); } /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// // List high score /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// // Return a list of high scores with "|" as the delimiter if ($gameid_safe) { $query = "select * from $tname where gameid='$gameid_safe' order by score desc limit 10"; $view_data = mysqli_query($query)or die(mysqli_error()); while($row_data = mysqli_fetch_array($view_data)) { print($row_data["playername"]); print "|"; print ($row_data["score"]); print ("|"); print($row_data["scoredate"]); print("|"); } // We limit the score database to hold the number defined in the config script // First check to see how many records we have for this game $query1 ="select * from $tname where gameid = '$gameid_safe'"; $countresults = mysqli_query($query1)or die(mysqli_error()); $countofdeletes = mysqli_num_rows($countresults); if (mysqli_num_rows($countresults)>$score_number) { $query2 ="SELECT * FROM $tname WHERE gameid = '$gameid_safe' ORDER BY score DESC Limit $score_number,$countofdeletes"; $Get_data = mysqli_query($query2)or die (mysqli_error()); while($row_data = mysqli_fetch_array($Get_data)) { $id_delete = $row_data["id"]; $query3 = "Delete from $tname where id = $id_delete"; $Delete_data = mysqli_query($query3)or die (mysqli_error()); } } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have a database with two tables...

```
user
    id
    username
    password

scores
    id
    user_id
    score
    date
```

...and that users register/logon to the site before playing. Also, that when logged on the `user.id` is stored in a `SESSION` variable.

Lastly let's assume you use a `mysqli` database with `PDO`.

```
<?php

session_start();

$db_host = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'db_username';
$db_pass = 'db_password';
$db_name = 'db_name';

$pdo = new \pdo(
    "mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",
    $db_user,
    $db_pass,
    [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);

$userId = $_SESSION["user_id"] ?? null;
$score  = $_GET["score"]       ?? null;
$date   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if (!$userId) {
    // User isn't logged on
    // 
    exit;
}

if (!is_int($score)) {
    // Not a valid score
    // 
    exit;
}

$sql   = "INSERT INTO scores (`user_id`, `score`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$userId, $score, $date]);
```